# Do I need to reformat my drive?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, chmod, external-hdd

Learning the hard way that you can't change the permissions of an exfat volume.... I need to be able to scp from Windows to an external hard drive on my Ubuntu Server without using an intermediary folder and then completing the transfer via ssh. Do I need to just backup my data and reformat the drive as ext4 or does anybody know of a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you are correct and it's best to backup the data and format the drive as `ext4` or `xfs` or another filesystem that supports linux permissions if that's what you need.

Another method is to mount the drive with the `uid` and `umask` options. For example:

```
mount -t exfat /dev/sdc1 /mnt/drive -o gid=1568,umask=002
```

That would mount it with what are, in effect, 775 permissions with the group that has the gid of 1568 but it isn't viable if you want to change permissions dynamically and it doesn't always achieve the desired results. It would also require a group with that gid on whatever system the drive will be used and it would require the exact same mount options on every system every time it's mounted.

In closing, I'll reiterate that it's best to just format the drive as `ext4` as it'll give you exactly what you want.

Comment: This ended up being what I did, thank you for your detailed explanation! It really helps when people explain why and not just how 

Comment: @Ego If that is the case, then you can accept my answer so that it shows that it resolved your issue and so that it will help others.

Comment: I’m not exactly sure how  I added the green check mark but I’m not sure if that is what I was supposed to do.

Comment: @Ego Yes, that is how you accept an answer. You can see it now that you've selected it and it's highlighted.